# Overriding mixins in LESS

Tags: less, less-mixins

when defining a mixin multiple times in `LESS`, and later calling that mixin as follows

```
.background-color() {
    background: red;
}

.background-color() {
    background: yellow;
}

body {
    .background-color;
}
```

the result will be a combined output from all the defined mixins

```
body {
  background: red;    // << output from mixin #1
  background: yellow; // << output from mixin #2
}
```

while when you apply the same scenario in both Sass & Stylus ( using their own syntax of course ), when you call a mixin that is defined multiple times across your stylesheets, **Only** the last defined one will be executed ( it will override all previously defined mixins ) as follows.

result `Sass` and `Stylus`

```
body {
  background: yellow; // << output from mixin #2
}
```

how can I override a mixin in `LESS` so that the output will be from the last defined mixin ?

Comment: I never used `less`, but why would you have two mixins with the same name? Seems like in less, when you use the same name again it just concatenates the rules.

Comment: @Cristy for multi-theme architecturing purposes, where a base theme will contain all the necessary variables and mixins, and when creating a child theme, you'll have the option to override base variables/ mixins or just inherit base ones.

Comment: Less inherits its semantics from CSS where a ruleset does not override  previous rulesets with the same name/selector but cascades. Though if those "base" mixins are written by you and thus "modifiable" you can use [`default` guard](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-default) to achieve what you want. But in general, yes, you have to use different idioms/design-patterns for your libraries since Less is fundamentally different language beside some basic stuff.

Comment: Despite that outputting background twice (red followed by yellow) is not that nicely readable later on, I think it will behave correctly when applied in the browser, since the latter rule will override the previous one.

But at the moment I not exactly sure whether that's generelly vaild for Less Mixins. But I guess, it is.

Comment: This topic is also answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100855/overwrite-less-mixin.

Answer (score 1):

You can not override them, alternatively use a variable to define the 'background-color'. For Less variables the last declared win.

Also read [Pattern-matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching)

In Less all matching mixins are compiled in the source. You can use namespace to prevent name collisions, for instance:

```
#ns1 {
.background-color() {
    background: red;
}
}

#ns2 {
.background-color() {
    background: yellow;
}
}
```

than you can use:

```
body {
    #ns2 > .background-color;
}
```

Double properties are also not removed to make some browser hacks possible, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property):

```
#myElement {
    width: 300px;
    width: 500px\9;
}
```

To find a solution for your use case you should reformulate your question and explain why you have these same named mixins in the first place.