# How to override mixin in Less

Tags: css, less

I want to override a property of the *.btn* mixin. I tried following code.

```
.btn() {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn() {
  text-align:left;
}

.button{
  .btn;
}
```

Less generates following code according to above snippet.

```
.button {
  text-align: center;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Of course I can try to use "!important" tag, but I don't want this. I am expecting following output.

```
.button {
  text-align: left;
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overwrite less mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100855/overwrite-less-mixin)

Comment: This post is too old. I am not sure whether it is answering or not.

Comment: If you can modify the original `.btn` than something like [`default()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-default) will do the trick. If you can't then you can't remove the original code (just like you can't remove already defined styles in CSS itself, note that "overriding" does not mean "removing"). If it's only about optimization - use css-minifiers (most of descent css-optimizers remove redundant properties just fine).

Comment: And `!important` would have absolutely no effect in this case